# How do I fully cut off list elements of unknown height partially hidden by overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, list, twitter, hidden

I have some javascript pulling status updates from a twitter feed, and a `div` element with a set height set to `overflow:hidden`. The problem is that that hidden doesn't completely cut off a list element, but cuts literally where the height stops.

How can I remove the entire `li` element?  I never know the height of each list element because the size of the twitter status varies.

This code spits out an unordered list with list elements of undefined height:
...
EDIT:

Here's the majority of the code.  The $param variables are user inputs.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#twitterbox { border: 1.5px $paramborder $parambordercolor; width: $paramwidth; height: $paramheight; overflow: hidden; display: block; }
#twitter_update_list { padding-left: 30px; list-style-image:url(local/smalltwitter.png);}
#twitter_update_list li { word-wrap: break-word; margin-right: 10px; }
#twitter_update_list li a { display: block; text-align: right;}
#twitter_update_list li span a { display: inline; text-align: left;}
-->
</style>

<div id="twitterbox">
<div class="tabletitle" id="twittertitle" style="width:100%">$paramheader</div>
<div id="twitter_div">
<ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$generalUtil.urlEncode("$paramuser").concat(".json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=$paramcount")">
</script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementById("twitter_update_list");
var sHeight = list.scrollHeight;
var dHeight = document.getElementById("twitterbox").offsetHeight;
var titleHeight = document.getElementById("twittertitle").offsetHeight;

while (sHeight > dHeight-titleHeight) {
  list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
  sHeight =  list.scrollHeight;
}
</script>
```

Two things.  For the most part it was working.  Within the li element the twitter script generates a span element and an anchor.  If it cut off at the span, it would remove the entire list element, but not if it cut off at the anchor, then it would show that.  Now, however, it's late at night and I must've done something cause the feed itself isn't working.  Is this the most efficient way of doing things

Comment: put some code or setup a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already populating the div with javascript, you can check if its [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) is greater than the `height`. If it is, remove list items from the bottom until `scrollHeight <= height`.

Comment: I'm not that good with javascript.  What's the best way to remove a list element?

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually add contents to that div? The place where you process the json returned by twitter.

Comment: The code you posted is correct, you just seem to have a small difference in your calculation preventing the last semi-visible item to be removed. Try something like `while (sHeight > dHeight-titleHeight-20)`. See http://jsfiddle.net/cTzrS/1/

Comment: Couple of things.  It only works if I change the code to [dHeight="$paramheight"].  For some reason if I use [var dHeight = document.getElementById("twitterbox").offsetHeight;] it doesn't work.  Also, changing it to paramheight and then adding the '-20' made it work completely.  Why 20, specifically?  Why isn't it calculating the correct height without that difference?

Comment: I'm not sure why, maybe there are extra margins on the `<ul>`. The 20px I suggested is a visual approximation...

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase the question is why doesn't dHeight-titleHeight equal the height of twitter_update_list.  I would use $paramheight, but then it won't work for percentages...

Comment: The actual answer is: use `clientHeight` instead of `offsetHeight`- http://jsfiddle.net/cTzrS/2/

Comment: The use of clientHeight did not seem to fix the need for the offset of 20.